# Kendo Grid Footertemplate export to Excel

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid with footertemplate. The grid is all working fine, but if I want to export it to Excel, I also want the footertemplate to be included but in different rows. How can I make the footer in Excel to be on different rows like the grid? Thanks for the help.

ex.
If I have footertemplate with Table and 2 TR, then I export to excel I want it to 2rows. Currently it combines everything on a single cell.

I'm just new on using this site so I cannot upload any image yet.

Comment: You cant unless you add you own grid export parser. I did something similar and kendo columns have enough meta-data that if you wanted to tackle this you could, however, out of the box it is not supported.

Comment: Thanks Irb. It is possible to post some example on doing that?

Comment: If you are using the built in export function that came out in a recent release then my suggestion will  not help. I have a LOT of code that will  and generate a PDF or XLS file based on kendo grid columns, data and grouping. I will post it if you would like, however, this will not help if you are using the built in method.